# Execute JavaScript function from object

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible to execute function this way:

```
this.values(value);
```

not

```
this.values[value]();
this.values[value].call();
```

If so, how? Or any other methods? Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
write: function(value) {

  this.values = {
    "red": function() { /* do something */ },
    "orange": function() { /* do something */ },
    "blue": function() { /* do something */ }
  };

  return this.values[value]();

}

write("red");
```

Comment: I don't see a problem here, you still get to call write("red"), don't you? Might be worth moving the values map outside the function if you'll need it elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

May be you could use a var inside:

```
write: function(value) {

  var values = {
    red: function() { /* do something */ },
    orange: function() { /* do something */ },
    blue: function() { /* do something */ }
  };

  return values[value];

}
```

And return the function instead of running it inside. And call it after.

Comment: Best to put the keys (red, orange, blue) in quotes in case you accidentally use a keyword.

Comment: @Phil H, you're right, It's a bad habit, I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

No. But there isn't anything wrong with how its done at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this:

```
write: function(value) {    
  switch(value){
    case "red":
    /* do something */
    break;

    case "orange":
    /* do something */
    break;

    case "blue":
    /* do something */
    break;

    default:
    /* do something */
    break;
  }    
}

write("red");
```